# Look for discount

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a check for showing how much discount you get by entering the size of order.

This is my structure:

```
1-11 pcs    |    50% discount    |    21,69 euro/piece
12-23 pcs   |    52,5% discount  |    20,61 euro/piece
```

Etc, till 600 pcs...

What's the best solution? Getting everything in an array and check it? Or do I need to just use if statements like:

```
if($pieces > 0 && $pieces < 12) {
```

and

```
if($pieces > 11 && $pieces < 24) {
```

etc.

Please let me know what you guys think.

Comment: Probably best to store each of the different ranges in a table and query the table based on how many the customer has in their cart. - `select * from product_qty_discount where ProductID = 1 and (qty > 0 and qty <= 12)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to store configuration in a form of array/db table like that:

```
lo_limit | hi_limit | discount
```

Then check it inside loop to find current discount for a certain amount of pieces:

```
foreach($rules as $rule) {
   if($pieces > $rule['lo_limit'] && $pieces < $rule['hi_limit']) {
      $discount = $rule['discount'];

      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use fixed values (like the one you provide)

```
$ordered = 15;
$discount = round( ($ordered / 12), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
$discount = 50 + ($discount * 2.5);
```

else use Baldrs solution